# $A\otimes M \otimes A$ projective as $A^e$-module, where $A$ and $M$ are projective over commutative ring $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra, $k$ a commutative ring and $M$ an $A$ bimodule. Suppose that both $A$ and $M$ are projective as modules over $k$. Why then $A\otimes M \otimes A$ is projective as left $A^e := A \otimes A^{op}$ module? Here all tensors are taken over $k$ and action is given by $$A^e \times A\otimes M \otimes A \to A\otimes M \otimes A \\ (a\otimes b, a_1\otimes m \otimes a_2) \to aa_1\otimes m \otimes a_2 b$$

Attempt 1: There is a free $k$-module $F$ and $k$-module $M'$ such that $M\oplus M'=F$. By tensoring under $k$ on left and on the right, one gets $A \otimes M \otimes A \oplus A\otimes M' \otimes A = A\otimes F \otimes A$... If I could justify that $A\otimes F \otimes A$ is free as **$A^e$**-module, I'm done. However, I'am aware that I didn't use the projectivity of $A$.

Attempt 2: It suffices to show that functor $Hom_{A^e} (A\otimes M \otimes A,-) $ is exact. By adjoint functior theorem for modules this functor is isomorphic to $Hom_k(A, Hom_k(M, Hom_{A^e}(A,-)))$, but I still can't conclude because of that mysterious $Hom_{A^e} (A,-)$.

Comment: Attempt 1 works : write $k^n=M\oplus M'$. Then $(A^e)^n=A\otimes k^n\otimes A= A\otimes M\otimes A\oplus A\otimes M'\otimes A$ is free. This shows that $A\otimes M\otimes A$ is a direct summand of a free module. You don't even need $A$ projective.

Comment: @Roland thank you very much for your answer. But how do you get the first equality $A^e = A \otimes k^n \otimes A$? Also, this works if $M$ is finitely generated. What about the case $M\oplus M'= k^I$ for $I$ any index set?

Comment: This is just the commutativity of tensor product with (arbitrary) direct sums : $A\otimes k^{(I)} \otimes A=(A\otimes\bigoplus_{I} k)\otimes A=(\bigoplus_I(A\otimes k))\otimes A=\bigoplus_I A\otimes A=\bigoplus_I A^e=(A^e)^{(I)}$.

Comment: Ok, so there is no essential difference between $A^e=A \otimes  A^{op}$ and $A\otimes A$, because $A$ and $A^{op}$ are the same objects?

Comment: $A$ and $A^{op}$ are the same as $k$-module, not as ring. Writting $A\otimes A^{op}$ mean that you consider $A\otimes A$ with a ring structure. Now $A\otimes A$ is endowed with a canonical $A^e$-module structure : $(a\otimes b)(m\otimes n)=am\otimes nb$. And the equality I wrote is compatible with this structure (check it). So this is indeed an isomorphism of $A^e$-module.

Comment: By the way, attempt 2 also works, but your adjunction was wrong. The right adjunction is (an extension-restriction of scalar adjunction) : $Hom_{A^e}(A\otimes M\otimes A,N)=Hom_k(M,N)$ where the map from left to right is given by $f\mapsto (m\mapsto f(1\otimes m\otimes 1))$ and the map from right to left is $g\mapsto (a\otimes m\otimes b\mapsto ag(m)b)$. Check that these maps are inverse to each other.